# How to deploy helmchart containing docker image from private registry on azure kubernetes cluster?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, gitlab

I want to deploy a Helmchart that takes a Docker image as an input parameter.
This image lives in a private GitLab registry.

When I deploy this on a local Kubernetes cluster it does work, though I have the idea that I have to pull the image using `docker pull registry.gitlab.com/<group_name>/<repo_name>/<image_name>` because it otherwise raises an error that it can't reach it.
To be honest, I'm also not sure why this is.

Now I have a Kubernetes cluster deployed on Azure and my `kubectl` is correctly pointing to that cluster.
It works when I deploy the Helmchart using a public Docker image, but when I pass an image in a private repo it times out.

Could someone maybe point me in the direction of why it somehow can't reach the private repo while working with my local cluster?
And could someone explain how to let the Kubernetes cluster on Azure reach the private repo?

Comment: Have you gone through the Kubernetes documentation on [Using a private registry](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#using-a-private-registry)?  Helm is not special here; any way you'd provide the `image:` and `imagePullSecrets:` would just get passed through to Kubernetes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks for the suggestion, I did, but I think I missed something.
I got it working now with the right Kubernetes secrets and configuration of the serviceaccount.